# How to bind click event on iframes that don't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe, binding

I want to bind an event on some iframes that are dynamically created on a page.

There is a way to bind events on regular elements that don't exist yet on page, using jQuery's .on() method, and passing a selector as second parameter. Like this :

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', () => { 
  // some code 
});
```

But iframe behaves differently I guess. This won't work:

```
$(document).on('click', 'iframe', () => { 
  // some code 
});
```

Also I thought of these:

```
$(window).on('click', 'document', () => {});
// or
$(document).on('click', 'body', () => {});
```

None of them worked.

Also I thought of another approach:

```
$(document).on('load', 'iframe', e => {
  $(e.target).contents().find('body').on('click', () => {
    // some code
  });
});
```

Didn't even bind the load event for iframes.

I MIGHT be able to handle it with completely different approach. I can bind the click event else where in code, each time an iframe is created, and they are infact "existed" in the page, then I might be able to bind any event I want to them. But I want to do that as the last solution. 
If there is a way to bind these events on page load for any iframes that will be created dynamically in the page, please suggest a solution.

UPDATE: I am on the same-domain, so the cross-origin restrictions don't apply.

Comment: Listening for click events in an iframe *at all* doesn't really work, though you can check when the window gets blurred and see if the new active element is the iframe (first click only)

Comment: $('iframe').contents().find('body').click(() => {
     
});

Comment: @CertainPerformance The code above, binds a click event on an iframe successfully and it works perfectly.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Also I don't understand why you closed this thread as duplicate when the link you provided is clearly about something different. I already know how to bind events on iframe. I just want to know how to do it dynamically. When the iframe doesn't exist yet and I cannot select it using regular methods. Wasn't my explanations clear enough?

Comment: Oh, you're on the same-domain, so the cross-origin restrictions don't apply, sorry about that. Events inside an iframe don't bubble out of it, so I *think* you'll have to attach a listener when the iframe is created, since event delegation on the top window doesn't work. The iframe could also use `postMessage` that the top level listens for.